# openjpa Existing column incompatible

Tags: warnings, openjpa

I'm new to openjpa and get this warning.

```
Existing column ... is incompatible with the same column name in the given schema definition.
```

It lists the differences and with a field(varchar) the size differs that is it shows 150 and 255. 150 is the size I've specified as size in db, but I'm not sure about the 255. In the entity class the corresponding field of type String.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenJPA assumes String columns are going to be 255 in the DB. Since your column is not, you can specify that non-default value with the @javax.persistence.Column annotation.

```
@Column(name = "BOOYA_MSG", length = 150)
protected String message;
```